# seaborn line plot set transparency for markers

Tags: python, seaborn

How to set transparency of markers and lines separately in `seaborn.lineplot`?

I have a set of points, and I want to draw a line plot connecting all of them. I want the lines be more transparent than markers. How to do that?

Here is my goal:[image]

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

matplotlib.rcParams['legend.handlelength'] = 0
matplotlib.rcParams['legend.numpoints'] = 1

data = [{'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 1, 'time': 181.0, 'auc': 69.76}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 2, 'time': 193.0, 'auc': 71.12}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 3, 'time': 256.0, 'auc': 71.84}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 4, 'time': 302.0, 'auc': 71.87}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 5, 'time': 365.0, 'auc': 71.89}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 8, 'time': 602.0, 'auc': 71.87}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 10, 'time': 743.0, 'auc': 71.84}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 1, 'time': 82.0, 'auc': 69.01}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 2, 'time': 105.0, 'auc': 69.45}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 3, 'time': 171.0, 'auc': 70.11}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 4, 'time': 224.0, 'auc': 70.36}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 5, 'time': 279.0, 'auc': 70.74}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 8, 'time': 517.0, 'auc': 70.81}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 10, 'time': 654.0, 'auc': 70.98}]

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
g = sns.lineplot(x='time', y='auc', data=data, markers=['o','v'], markersize=7, sort=False, hue='method', style="method", dashes=False, linestyle=None)
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

Comment: There should be a Alpha setting for marker. Provide us the full code line for the seaborn.lineplot

Comment: You could try to add "alpha= 0.6" in the lineplot(), but it effects line transperency as well. Probably won't do it for you. Don't know about markers exatcly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seaborn seems to make the colors lighter.  You can loop through the generated dots and change their lightness. (The dots are stored in `ax.collections`.) The lightness ranges from `0` (black) to `1` (white).

As now the dots and the lines have a different color, and the lines are drawn on top of the dots, the result looks a bit strange. You could change the `zorder` of the lines to move them to the back.

The legend should be created again (via `ax.legend`) to show the new marker colors.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
flights = sns.load_dataset('flights')
## markers = [".",",","o","v","^","<",">","1","2","3","4","8","s","p","P","*","h","H","+","x","X","D","d","|","_",0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
markers = ["o", "v", "^", "<", ">", "8", "s", "*", "h", "H", "P", "p"]
ax = sns.pointplot(data=flights, x='year', y='passengers', hue='month', markers=markers, palette='Set3')
for dots in ax.collections:
    color = dots.get_facecolor()
    dots.set_color(sns.set_hls_values(color, l=0.5))
    dots.set_alpha(1)
for line in ax.lines:
    line.set_zorder(0)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.02), loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.lineplot with darker marker colors]

#update

The above answer was written before you added the code. For the example in the code, you could call `lineplot` twice. (Note that 'axes level functions' return an `ax`, while ['figure level functions'](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) return a seaborn grid-like data structure, e.g. a `FacetGrid`. Therefore, a custom is to only use `g` for the name of the return value of figure-level functions, and a name similar to `ax` for an axes-level function. Such naming makes it easier to see how existing example code can be applied.)

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

matplotlib.rcParams['legend.handlelength'] = 0
matplotlib.rcParams['legend.numpoints'] = 1

data = [{'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 1, 'time': 181.0, 'auc': 69.76}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 2, 'time': 193.0, 'auc': 71.12}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 3, 'time': 256.0, 'auc': 71.84}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 4, 'time': 302.0, 'auc': 71.87}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 5, 'time': 365.0, 'auc': 71.89}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 8, 'time': 602.0, 'auc': 71.87}, {'method': 'end-to-end', 'k': 10, 'time': 743.0, 'auc': 71.84}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 1, 'time': 82.0, 'auc': 69.01}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 2, 'time': 105.0, 'auc': 69.45}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 3, 'time': 171.0, 'auc': 70.11}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 4, 'time': 224.0, 'auc': 70.36}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 5, 'time': 279.0, 'auc': 70.74}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 8, 'time': 517.0, 'auc': 70.81}, {'method': 'first', 'k': 10, 'time': 654.0, 'auc': 70.98}]

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
sns.set_style('ticks')

ax = sns.lineplot(x='time', y='auc', data=data, markers=['o','v'], markersize=7, sort=False, hue='method', style='method',  dashes=False, linestyle='', alpha=1)
sns.lineplot(x='time', y='auc', data=data, sort=False, hue='method',   dashes=False,  alpha=0.3, legend=False, ax=ax)
ax.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

[image: two times sns.lineplot]

Comment: One more question, I want a short vertical line above the x/y-axis ticks (just like the picture in my question). How to do that?

Comment: Well I figured it out. I found the line appears after commenting removing grid style.

Comment: You can use `sns.set_style('ticks')`. I updated the plot.